# Memory not released in PopUp xamarin forms android application

Tags: memory, optimization, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using a popup to show a image popup in xamarin forms android application. Each time when i open and close the popup the memory spikes and this is not recollected. I am using a constructor to open the popup. How can we properly dispose the memory inside the popup when its closed.

//call from the parent page

```
await Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new ImagePopUp(imgSrc));
```

//ImagePopUp

```
public ImagePopUp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var tapgesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapgesture.Tapped += async (sender, e) => Handle_Clicked(sender, e);
            this.Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapgesture);
        }
        public ImagePopUp(ImageSource src) : this()
        {
            try
            {
                PopUpImageHolder.HeightRequest = App.ScreenHeight * 0.8;
                if (src != null)
                {

                    PopUpImageHolder.Source = src;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Task.Run(async () => await DisplayAlert("Alert", ex.Message, "OK"));
            }
```

and to close the popup i use

```
await PopupNavigation.PopAsync();
```

The image memory is spiking each time when i open the popup

Comment: The GC collections are *on demand*, based upon heap allocations, and not based upon reference counts hitting zero. The GC will run when the minor heap has run out of memory for new allocations...... if you wish to force a GC, call `GC.Collect()` : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/garbage_collection/

Comment: so is there any way we could actually reduce the memory imprint, because explicitly calling GC.Collect() is a bad applicaiton design right?

Comment: The imgSrc could also be kept somewhere in the parent page, that might not be disposed of.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas - Calling GC.Collect is just to prove that the memory will be collected, and its not a leak. If it does get collected with GC.Collect, then you don't need to worry about it. The OS will clean it up when its ready.

Comment: @GeorgeThomas Totally agree with Adam, use `GC.Collect` to verify that you are not *actually* leaking anything... I actually use a `Task.Run` at the application level that just loops `GC.Collect` and `Task.Delay(30000) when performing allocation profiling....

Comment: @AdamPedley Okay. i will try to keep the source in the parent and try

Comment: @GeorgeThomas - I was actually meaning that you should check to make sure it ISNT kept in the parent. :)

Comment: @AdamPedley oops i got it wrong sorry.  I tried and made the popup view singleton class now when i continuously open and close its not giving me any huge memory spikes.

Comment: @SushiHangover I will try that way